# Calling kernel_fpu_begin twice before kernel_fpu_end

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm using the `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end` functions in [asm/i387.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/i387.h?v=3.2#L310) to protect the FPU register states for some simple floating point arithmetic inside of a Linux kernel module.

I'm curious about the behavior of calling the `kernel_fpu_begin` function twice before the `kernel_fpu_end` function, and vice versa. For example:

```
#include <asm/i387.h>

double foo(unsigned num){
    kernel_fpu_begin();

    double x = 3.14;
    x += num;

    kernel_fpu_end();

    return x;
}

...

kernel_fpu_begin();

double y = 1.23;
unsigned z = 42;
y -= foo(z);

kernel_fpu_end();
```

In the `foo` function, I call `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end`; but `kernel_fpu_begin` was already called before the call to `foo`. Would this result in undefined behavior?

Furthermore, should I even be calling `kernel_fpu_end` inside the `foo` function? I return a **double** after the `kernel_fpu_end` call, which means accessing floating point registers is unsafe right?

My initial guess is just not to use the `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end` calls inside the `foo` function; but what if `foo` returned the **double** cast to **unsigned** instead -- the programmer wouldn't know to use `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end` outside of `foo`?

Comment: Exported now at `asm/fpu/api.h`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: no, it is incorrect to nest `kernel_fpu_begin()` calls, and it will lead to the userspace FPU state getting corrupted.

Medium answer: This won't work because `kernel_fpu_begin()` use the current thread's `struct task_struct` to save off the FPU state (`task_struct` has an architecture-dependent member `thread`, and on x86, `thread.fpu` holds the thread's FPU state), and doing a second `kernel_fpu_begin()` will overwrite the original saved state.  Then doing `kernel_fpu_end()` will end up restoring the wrong FPU state.

Long answer: As you saw looking at the actual implementation in `<asm/i387.h>`, the details are a bit tricky.  In older kernels (like the 3.2 source you looked at), the FPU handling is always "lazy" -- the kernel wants to avoid the overhead of reloading the FPU until it really needs it, because the thread might run and be scheduled out again without ever actually using the FPU or needing its FPU state.  So `kernel_fpu_end()` just sets the TS flag, which causes the next access of the FPU to trap and cause the FPU state to be reloaded.  The hope is that we don't actually use the FPU enough of the time for this to be cheaper overall.

However, if you look at newer kernels (3.7 or newer, I believe), you'll see that there is actually a second code path for all of this -- "eager" FPU.  This is because newer CPUs have the "optimized" XSAVEOPT instruction, and newer userspace uses the FPU more often (for SSE in memcpy, etc).  The cost of XSAVEOPT / XRSTOR is less and the chance of the lazy optimization actually avoiding an FPU reload is less too, so with a new kernel on a new CPU, `kernel_fpu_end()` just goes ahead and restores the FPU state.  (

However in both the "lazy" and "eager" FPU modes, there is still only one slot in the `task_struct` to save the FPU state, so nesting `kernel_fpu_begin()` will end up corrupting userspace's FPU state.

Comment: Theoretically, if I spawned a new kernel thread, would it be safe to call `kernel_fpu_begin` since the state would be saved to a different `task_struct` structure?

Comment: Sure, in the context of a different thread, you could call `kernel_fpu_begin` again.  That wouldn't truly be nested usage, since you are creating a new thread of execution.  (An analogy would be that you can do `mutex_lock()` twice on the same mutex if and only if you have two different threads)

Comment: By the way, in `kernel_fpu_begin` do you happen to know why the TS flag is only cleared if TS_USEDFPU is not set; is the TS flag just assumed to already be cleared if TS_USEDFPU is not set?

Comment: TS_USEDFPU being set means "FPU was used by this task this quantum".  I think you typed the opposite of what you meant, but the idea is correct: if TS_USEDFPU _is_ set, then this thread already used the FPU and hasn't been scheduled out, and so TS can't be set (since TS=1 means FPU instructions would cause an exception, and the kernel must already have dealt with that and cleared TS).

Answer (score 0):

I'm commenting the [asm/i387.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/i387.h?v=3.2#L310) Linux source code (version 3.2) with what I understand to be occurring.

```
static inline void kernel_fpu_begin(void)
{
        /* get thread_info structure for current thread */
        struct thread_info *me = current_thread_info();

        /* preempt_count is incremented by 1
         * (preempt_count > 0 disables preemption,
         *  while preempt_count < 0 signifies a bug) */
        preempt_disable();

        /* check if FPU has been used before by this thread */
        if (me->status & TS_USEDFPU)
                /* save the FPU state to prevent clobbering of
                 * FPU registers, then reset the TS_USEDFPU flag */
                __save_init_fpu(me->task);
        else
                /* clear the CR0.TS bit to prevent
                 * unnecessary FPU task context saving */
                clts();
}

static inline void kernel_fpu_end(void)
{
        /* set CR0.TS bit (signifying the processor switched
         * to a new task) to enable FPU task context saving */
        stts();

        /* attempt to re-enable preemption
         * (preempt_count is decremented by 1);
         * reschedule thread if needed
         * (thread will not be preempted if preempt_count != 0) */
        preempt_enable();
}
```

The `FXSAVE` instruction is typically used to save the FPU state. However, I believe the memory destination stays the same every time `kernel_fpu_begin` is called within the same thread; unfortunately that would mean that `FXSAVE` will overwrite the previously saved FPU state.

Therefore I suspect that you **CANNOT** safely nest `kernel_fpu_begin` calls.

What I still cannot understand though is how the FPU state is being restored, since the `kernel_fpu_end` call does not appear to execute a `FXRSTOR` instruction. Also, why is the `CR0.TS` bit set in the `kernel_fpu_end` call if we are no longer using the FPU?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as you defined some double variable & `foo` is also returning the double value; you have to use `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end` calls outside `foo` [also.](http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2012-November/006462.html)

---

[Similar Problem](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?12,409657) also have this which have certain instances where you can code without using  `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end` calls.

Comment: This is wrong.  You'll corrupt FPU state if you nest `kernel_fpu_begin`.