# Why are SIMD instructions not used in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver, simd, ispc

I couldn't find much use of SIMD instructions (like SSE/AVX) in kernel (except one place where they were used to speedup parity computation of RAID6).

Q1) Any specific reason for this or just the lack of use-case?

Q2) What needs to be done today if I want to use SIMD instruction, in say a device driver?

Q3) How hard will it be to incorporate framework like ISPC into kernel (just for experimentation)?

Answer (score 11):

Saving/restoring FPU (including SIMD vector registers) state is more expensive than just integer GP register state.  It's simply not worth the cost in most cases.

**In Linux kernel code, all you have to do is call `kernel_fpu_begin()` / `kernel_fpu_end()` around your code.  This is what the RAID drivers do.**  See http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/kernel_fp.html.

---

x86 doesn't have any future-proof way to save/restore one or a couple vector registers.  (Other than manual save/restore of an `xmm` register using legacy SSE instructions, potentially causing [SSE/AVX transition stalls on Intel CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake) if user-space had the upper halves of any ymm/zmm registers dirty).

The reason legacy SSE works is that some Windows drivers were already doing this when Intel wanted to introduce AVX, so they invented that transition-penalty stuff instead of having legacy SSE instructions zero the upper 128b of ymm registers.  (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086289/224132) for more detail on that design decision.)  So basically we can blame Windows binary-only drivers for the SSE/AVX transition-penalty mess.

IDK about non-x86 architectures, and whether the existing SIMD instruction sets have a future-proof way to save/restore a register that will continue to work for longer vectors.  ARM32 might, if extensions continue the pattern of using multiple 32-bit FP registers as single wider register.  (e.g. `q2` is composed of `s8` through `s11`.)  So saving/restoring a couple `q` registers should be future-proof, if a 256b NEON extension simply lets you use 2 `q` registers as one 256b register.  Or if the new wider vectors are separate, and don't extend the existing registers.

Comment: Related: [memcpy moving 128 bit in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34011852/224132).  My answer also mentions that `kernel_fpu_end()` actually does an "eager" restore of FPU state in Linux 3.7 and later, so don't use multiple begin/end calls around small chunks of work.

Comment: Also related: [Why am I able to perform floating point operations inside a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15883947) - you can't *safely*, you're corrupting user-space state.